# how to re-arrange page using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a simple website and i cannot figure out how to do a couple of things.

1. There is a nav bar, but it is stuck underneath the image at the top, how do i move it down?
2. I would like to arrange all of the ul's to be alongside each other, horizontally not vertically.

```css
.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.nav a {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 250px;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('http://i118.photobucket.com/albums/o117/Shawnthebro/bandicam2014-03-2311-20-03-210_zpse7f7712f.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 350px;
}
.page h3 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-top: 250px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.page ul {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-left: 75px;
}
.page a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-left: 70px;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
background:url(./image.png) no-repeat top center;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">History of Gaming</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Atari</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Other Games</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Future</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Gaming: Then, Now & Beyond</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page">
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>What is gaming?</li>
              <li>Pong</li>
              <li>Technology Boom</li>
            </ul>
            <p><a href="#">Learn more about the history of gaming</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Atari</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>40 years of fun</li>
              <li>Who is Nolan Bushnell</li>
              <li>Bought & Sold</li>
            </ul>
            <p><a href="#">Learn more about Atari</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Other Games</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>PC</li>
              <li>Xbox</li>
              <li>PlayStation</li>
            </ul>
            <p><a href="#">Learn more about other games</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Future</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Gaming in society</li>
              <li>Who is driving who?</li>
              <li>CrowdFunding</li>
            </ul>
            <p><a href="#">Learn about future gaming</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can either change the `jumbotron` to `position: relative/static`

or

make the nav go down a bit:

```
.nav{
margin-top: 350px;
}
```

Regarding the `ul`s:

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;  
}
ul li {
  display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>link</li>
  <li>link</li>
  <li>link</li>
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

First move all of the `jumbotron` above the `nav` in the HTML. Set them both to `display: block;` if you need to.

For the `ul`s, add

```
.page ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

for all of them on the page